# Traducción para Gallivanting en español

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término

Ayer uno de mis compañeros de oficina dijo que se había pasado la tarde anterior *galivanting*. Gallivanting (o galavanting) se define como:

> (From [Cambridge dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/gallivant))
>
> to visit or go to a lot of different places, enjoying yourself and having few worries or responsibilities
>
> (From [Merriam-webster dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gallivant))
>
> 1:  to go about usually ostentatiously or indiscreetly with members of the opposite sex
>
> 2:  to travel, roam, or move about for pleasure

Mi problema al traducir esta palabra al español es que se me ocurre `salir` (de marcha, a pasarlo bien, etc,) para "go around from one place to another in the pursuit of pleasure or entertainment.".

[WordReference](http://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=gallivanting) traduce *gallivanting* como `callejear` y `socializar`. Pero según el DRAE *[callejear](http://dle.rae.es/?id=6por6HV)*  simplemente alude a "andar frecuentemente y sin necesidad de calle en calle". De igual manera, "socializar" no recoge por completo el concepto de "andar de un lado para otro en busca de diversión, juerga, etc."

Hay mejores traducciones para *gallivanting* que "salir" (de marcha / de fiesta), "callejear" o "socializar"?

Comment: *Salir de parranda.*  Tenemos un gato que sale de parranda.  Regresa cuando le da la gana.

Comment: @aparente001 pues no es mala opción, si la explicas un poco te da para respuesta.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo - gracias, así lo haré.  Lo que pasa es que no sé cuáles de mis expresiones son univerales y cuáles son mexicanismos.

Comment: @aparente001 en España esta la usamos y por lo que veo en el [DRAE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=RyiayWB) es genérica. En general, si miras en el DRAE y el DAMER puedes saber dónde se usa.

Comment: En Chile: _carretear_.

Comment: @Rodrigo - ¿Por qué no agregas una respuesta?

Answer (score 4):

[***andar de parranda***](http://www.wordreference.com/es/en/translation.asp?spen=andar%20de%20parranda)

> estar de fiesta  
> be out partying   
> go out on the town

*(wordreference.com)*

Ejemplos:

> Tenemos un gato que sale de parranda. Regresa cuando le da la gana.  (Busca un ratón por acá, una ardillita por allá, y de paso saluda a ciertas vecinas cariñosas.  Este gato está operado, pero obviamente algunos no.  Pero creo que *gallivant* y *andar de parranda* funcionan, ambos, para ambos casos (con amoríos o sin ellos).
>
> Anoche salimos de parranda.  Creo que pasamos por cuatro o cinco fiestas diferentes.

Comment: Yo incluso añadiría la definición de la RAE de [parranda](http://dle.rae.es/?id=RyiayWB): "Juerga bulliciosa, especialmente la que se hace yendo de un sitio a otro." Hoy día incluso se usa en el sentido de "estar por ahí disfrutando de la vida". En España se conoce muy bien la expresión.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo - "estar por ahí disfrutando de la vida" va muy de acuerdo con *gallivanting*.  Me da la misma sensación que *gallivant*.  Parece que la equivalencia es bastante buena.